# Swift 3 Core Data relation does not delete related objects

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode8, relationship, ios10

I am writing a program using Xcode 8.3.3 and Swift 3.1 for iOS 10.3 (So I can use `NSPersistentContainer` with default Core Data Stack). I want to write very simple Core Data model with relationship. Problem is I do not know how to work with relations. I want to make a simple relation one to many. I already know, how to add this relations on Core Data scheme, there is screenshot:

[image: Core Data Scheme]

So, one chat can have a lot of messages, one message can have only one chat. Delete rules on both ends are set to Cascade. I have my own class to work with Core Data objects (I am not generating it). Also, I have made manual models to each entity. But, when I am deleting chat, messages, associated with this chat, are not deleting. Question is: what should I do to force this relation work in proper way? And, why it is not deleting anything automatically?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Relations in Core Data do not work automatically. I have to understand how to use them properly.